# Not all Mecurial changesets are visible using RhodeCode

Tags: linux, mercurial, tortoisehg, rhodecode

Using RhodeCode 1.5.4.  Our remote Mercurial repositories exist on Linux RedHat servers.  We typically use Tortoise to clone these repos locally via RhodeCode to Windows environment, do work locally, then push back to the remote repositories.  This all works fine.  However, I am also the owner of the remote repositories, and as such, I sometimes make changes to these repositories via scripts executed directly on the remote repository.  These changes are not reflected in RhodeCode.  I have to pull the repo locally, make a change, then push to the remote repo before changes made directly on the server show up in RhodeCode.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to Cache system that RhodeCode is using. You can use this(https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/api/api.html#invalidate-cache) API call to trigger manual cache invalidation. Or simply go to repository settings > caches> invalidate cache to manually trigger that.